# Unable to Execute Watir Hover or Mouseover Main Nav Menu

Tags: java, drop-down-menu, hover, mouseover, watir

I have been trying for about 2 days searching through the forums here and on google groups and none of what I have found has worked. Basically the top nav menu is put into the following HTML:

```
<div id="topNav">
<div id="headerLogo">  
<div id="mainNav">
<ul id="nav">
<li id="navTab01" class="manageUsers">
<a class="mainNavItem" title="Manage Users And Groups" href="#"> </a>
<ul class="dropdown" style="display: none;">
</li>
<li id="navTab02" class="manageContent">
<a class="mainNavItem current" title="Manage Content" href="#"> </a>
<ul class="dropdown" style="display: none;">
<li class="manageSubRegions">
<li class="manageBusinessDirectoryEntries">
<a class="dropdownItemHasFlyout current" href="/BusinessDirectoryEntry"> Business Directory</a>
<ul class="flyout" style="display: none; left: 224px;">
</li>
<li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="navTab03" class="manageFinancials">
<li id="navTab04" class="runReports">
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

The menu Item I want to manipulate is navTab002 which has the expanded HTML Of:

```
<li id="navTab02" class="manageContent">
<a class="mainNavItem current" title="Manage Content" href="#"> </a>
<ul class="dropdown" style="display: none;">
<li class="manageSubRegions">
<a class="current" href="/SubRegion"> Regions</a>  
</li>
<li class="manageBusinessDirectoryEntries">
<a class="dropdownItemHasFlyout current" href="/BusinessDirectoryEntry"> Business    Directory</a>
<ul class="flyout" style="display: none; left: 224px;">
<li class="businessDirectoryEntryQuickAdd">
<a class="current" href="/BusinessDirectoryEntry/QuickAdd"> Quick Add</a>
</li>
<li class="manageBusinessCustomListings">
<a class="current" href="/BusinessDirectoryCustomListing"> Sectors</a>  
</li>
<li class="manageBusinessDirectoryProfileTypes">
<a class="current" href="/BusinessDirectoryProfileType"> Profile Types</a>
</li>
<li class="manageBusinessDirectoryPrivateTypes">
<a class="current" href="/BusinessDirectoryPrivateType"> Private Types</a>
</li>
<li class="displayOptions">
<a class="current" href="/DisplayOption">Display Options</a>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
```

I want to click on the 3rd item in the drop down list on hover over (or mouse click) either work with it manually.

The java script is using hoverIntent which (may) be causing a problem for me - not sure.

When I used the console saving during a manual run I got:

DOMNodeRemoved
DOMSubtreeModified
DOMNodeInserted
DOMSubtreeModified
DOMNodeRemoved
DOMSubtreeModified
DOMNodeInserted
DOMSubtreeModified
DOMNodeRemoved
DOMSubtreeModified

a bazzillion times.

This is the log of coding I have attempted with ruby Watir:

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'watir'
=> true
 <Watir::Browser.start("http://services.leedsgrenville.com/")
=> #<Watir::IE:0x4c618ca8 url="http://services.leedsgrenville.com/" title="Admin
istration">
<ink(:index, 1).attribute_value("/BusinessDirectoryEntry")
NoMethodError: undefined method `li' for main:Object
    from (irb):3
    from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
irb(main):004:0> browser.li(:text, 'Manage Users & groups').link(:index, 1).at>
Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException: Unable to locate element, using {:tag_
name=>["li"], :text=>"Manage Users & groups"}
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.1.0/lib/watir-c
lassic/element.rb:66:in `assert_exists'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.1.0/lib/watir-c
lassic/element.rb:135:in `document'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.1.0/lib/watir-c
lassic/locator.rb:31:in `document'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.1.0/lib/watir-c
lassic/locator.rb:136:in `each_element'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.1.0/lib/watir-c
lassic/locator.rb:21:in `block in each'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.1.0/lib/watir-c
lassic/locator.rb:20:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.1.0/lib/watir-c
lassic/locator.rb:20:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.1.0/lib/watir-c
lassic/locator.rb:147:in `locate'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.1.0/lib/watir-c
lassic/element.rb:33:in `locate'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.1.0/lib/watir-c
lassic/element.rb:63:in `assert_exists'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.1.0/lib/watir-c
lassic/element.rb:407:in `attribute_value'
    from (irb):4
    from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
irb(main):005:0> browser.li.flash
=> nil
irb(main):006:0> browser.li(id => "navTab02").flash
NameError: undefined local variable or method `id' for main:Object
    from (irb):6
    from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
irb(main):007:0> browser.li(id => "navTab02").flash
NameError: undefined local variable or method `id' for main:Object
    from (irb):7
    from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
irb(main):008:0> browser.li(index, 2).flash
NameError: undefined local variable or method `index' for main:Object
    from (irb):8
    from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
irb(main):009:0> browser.li(index, 2)
NameError: undefined local variable or method `index' for main:Object
    from (irb):9
    from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
<nk(:text, /Manage Content/).fire_event('onmouseover')
=> ""
<(:text, /Manage Content/).fire_event('onmouseover')
=> ""
<(:text, /Manage Content/).fire_event('onmouseover')
=> ""
irb(main):013:0> browser.link(:text, /Manage Content/).flash
=> nil
irb(main):014:0> browser.link(:text, /navTab01/).flash
Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException: Unable to locate element, using {:tag_
name=>["a"], :text=>/navTab01/}
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.1.0/lib/watir-c
lassic/element.rb:66:in `assert_exists'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.1.0/lib/watir-c
lassic/element.rb:280:in `flash'
    from (irb):14
    from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
irb(main):015:0> browser.link(:text, /navTab01/).flash
Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException: Unable to locate element, using {:tag_
name=>["a"], :text=>/navTab01/}
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.1.0/lib/watir-c
lassic/element.rb:66:in `assert_exists'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.1.0/lib/watir-c
lassic/element.rb:280:in `flash'
    from (irb):15
    from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
irb(main):016:0> browser.link(:text, /Manage Content/).flash
=> nil
irb(main):017:0> browser.link(:text, /Manage Content/).flash
=> nil
irb(main):018:0>
<(:class => 'manageContent', :text => 'Manage Content').link.click
Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException: Unable to locate element, using {:tag_
name=>["li"], :class=>"manageContent", :text=>"Manage Content"}
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.1.0/lib/watir-c
lassic/element.rb:66:in `assert_exists'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.1.0/lib/watir-c
lassic/element.rb:135:in `document'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.1.0/lib/watir-c
lassic/locator.rb:31:in `document'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.1.0/lib/watir-c
lassic/locator.rb:136:in `each_element'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.1.0/lib/watir-c
lassic/locator.rb:21:in `block in each'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.1.0/lib/watir-c
lassic/locator.rb:20:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.1.0/lib/watir-c 
lassic/locator.rb:20:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.1.0/lib/watir-c
lassic/locator.rb:147:in `locate'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.1.0/lib/watir-c
lassic/element.rb:33:in `locate'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.1.0/lib/watir-c
lassic/element.rb:63:in `assert_exists'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.1.0/lib/watir-c
lassic/element.rb:412:in `perform_action'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.1.0/lib/watir-c
lassic/element.rb:269:in `click!'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.1.0/lib/watir-c
lassic/element.rb:211:in `click'
    from (irb):19
    from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
<(:class => 'manageContent', :text => 'Business Directory').link.click
Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException: Unable to locate element, using {:tag_
name=>["li"], :class=>"manageContent", :text=>"Business Directory"}
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.1.0/lib/watir-c
lassic/element.rb:66:in `assert_exists'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.1.0/lib/watir-c
lassic/element.rb:135:in `document'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.1.0/lib/watir-c
lassic/locator.rb:31:in `document'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.1.0/lib/watir-c
lassic/locator.rb:136:in `each_element'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.1.0/lib/watir-c
lassic/locator.rb:21:in `block in each'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.1.0/lib/watir-c
lassic/locator.rb:20:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.1.0/lib/watir-c
lassic/locator.rb:20:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.1.0/lib/watir-c
lassic/locator.rb:147:in `locate'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.1.0/lib/watir-c
lassic/element.rb:33:in `locate'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.1.0/lib/watir-c
lassic/element.rb:63:in `assert_exists'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.1.0/lib/watir-c
lassic/element.rb:412:in `perform_action'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.1.0/lib/watir-c
lassic/element.rb:269:in `click!'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.1.0/lib/watir-c
lassic/element.rb:211:in `click'
    from (irb):20
    from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
irb(main):021:0> browser.div(:id, "mainNav").fire_event "onmouseover"
=> ""
irb(main):022:0> browser.div(:id, "mainNav").fire_event "onmouseover"
=> ""
irb(main):023:0> browser.link(:id => "navTab01").click
Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException: Unable to locate element, using {:tag_
name=>["a"], :id=>"navTab01"}
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.1.0/lib/watir-c
lassic/element.rb:66:in `assert_exists'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.1.0/lib/watir-c
lassic/element.rb:412:in `perform_action'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.1.0/lib/watir-c
lassic/element.rb:269:in `click!'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.1.0/lib/watir-c
lassic/element.rb:211:in `click'
    from (irb):23
    from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
irb(main):024:0> browser.link(:class => "manageUsers").click
Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException: Unable to locate element, using {:tag_
name=>["a"], :class=>"manageUsers"}
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.1.0/lib/watir-c
lassic/element.rb:66:in `assert_exists'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.1.0/lib/watir-c
lassic/element.rb:412:in `perform_action'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.1.0/lib/watir-c
lassic/element.rb:269:in `click!'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.1.0/lib/watir-c
lassic/element.rb:211:in `click'
    from (irb):24
    from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
irb(main):025:0> browser.div(:id, "mainNav").hover
NoMethodError: undefined method `hover' for #<Watir::Div:0x30b3610>
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.1.0/lib/watir-c
lassic/element.rb:431:in `method_missing'
    from (irb):25
    from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
irb(main):026:0> class Watir::Element
irb(main):027:1> def hover
irb(main):028:2> assert_exists
irb(main):029:2>
irb(main):030:2*   driver.action.move_to(@element).perform
irb(main):031:2> end
irb(main):032:1> end
=> nil
<ll(:text, "Manage Content").fire_event("onmouseover")
NoMethodError: undefined method `cell' for #<Watir::IE:0x3276978>
    from (irb):33
    from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
irb(main):034:0> require 'WET'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- WET
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:i
n `require'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:i
n `require'
    from (irb):34
    from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

The Actual Java Code is:

```
$("#mainNav, #mainNavDropdown").hoverIntent(
{
    interval: 200,
    timeout: 1000,
    over: function()
    {
        $(this).addClass("over");
        $("#mainNavDropdown").stop(true, true).slideDown(500,
                 function()
                 {
                     $(this).css("height", ""); // Make sure animation didn't screw up
                 });
    },
    out: function()
    {
        $(this).removeClass("over");
        if (!$("#mainNav, #mainNavDropdown").hasClass("over"))
            $("#mainNavDropdown").stop().slideUp(500,
                function()
                {
                    $(this).css("height", ""); // Make sure animation didn't screw up
                });
    }
});

// Hide the menu on body click
$("body")
    .click(function(evt)
    {
        if ($(evt.target)
                .parents()
                .andSelf()
                .filter("#mainNav, #mainNavDropdown").length == 0)
            $("#mainNavDropdown").stop().slideUp(300,
                function()
                {
                    $(this).css("height", ""); // Make sure animation didn't screw up
                });
    });
```

If anyone can attempt to help me that would be awesome!

Comment: Would you be able to create a test page or provide a login for the page? These kinds of problems are difficult to debug without something to work with.

Comment: You can find a similar site at http://www.crasustainability2011.com/en/index.asp - I cant get you to see the actual site as it is private :( the site provided functions similarly with respect to menus however. Hope that helps

Comment: On the CRA page, which link is at a level similar to what you need to achieve? I have been able to do "Sustainability Services > Services", but having some issues doing "Sustainability Services > Project Highlights > EHS Management Support".

Answer (score 2):

To hover with watir try the following:

```
browser.element(:attribute, 'value').fire_event 'mouseover'
```

Of course replace element, attribute, and value with your values.